# Can you file from where in a project a file is imported in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to understand how a specific javascript app works reading the source code.
I know there is a file that, at some point, gets executed, but the file has no exports so I am thinking that, in some other point in the code, there is an `import 'foo/bar'` statement causing the file to be run, but I don't know how to find where from.

Visual Studio Code has a feature that lets me see where a function has been defined or where is it used, is there a similar feature for tracking imports of a file?

Comment: Use the search feature to search thru all files for that `import 'foo/bar/`shortcut is `ctrl + shift + f`

Comment: There is also a custom extension https://github.com/oaprograms/vscode-extension-find-all-imports

Comment: @PhilipRollins The reason I didn't think of the search feature as a solution was because relative imports, the import might be foo/bar or ./bar or ../bar or whatever, and other files may share the same name in other directories (it was a simplified example but the file is index.js and there are several). The extension looks really promising tho

Comment: Very true, codelens might also help. I don't use it personally find it noisy but does show total references on functions if I remember correctly.